# Ramda: filter by "fuzzy search"

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

I have a list of IMDb's top 100 movies. Given the title, I was trying to find a way to "fuzzy search" through it. i.e., if you typed `"shaw"`, the results would display `"The Shawshank Redemption"`. If nothing is typed (i.e., `search` is an empty string), it would not filter any of the movies.

My selector is as follows:

```
export const selectMovies = createSelector(
  getMovies,
  getQueryParams,
  (movies, { search = '' }) => R.filter(
    R.propSatisfies(R.contains(search), 'title'),
    movies
  ),
)
```

Where `getMovies` is a function that returns a `Movie[]`, and `getQueryParams` returns an object that has the key `search` with a string value.

Right now, while I can get it to roughly filter by title, it seems to have a number of problems. For example, if I type in `"sha"`, I get the Shawshank Redemption. However, if I type in `"shaw"`, it doesn't get shawshank redemption.

Is there a good way to implement a string-based "fuzzy filter" with ramda?

Comment: Seems like the fuzzy filter is case sensitive, since sha is found twice in **Sha**w**sha**nk it hits on sha as in shank, but not sha as in Sha.

Comment: Does the previous comment give you enough information to solve it on your own?

Comment: Not quite, I have been working on applying `R.replace` to limit it to only characters and numbers, which has had some success

Answer (score 2):

This is untested, but I think you could easily write:

```
const containsInsensitive = child => parent => contains(toLower(child), toLower(parent))
```

Then replace

```
R.contains(search)
```

with

```
containsInsensitive(search)
```

That should be all it takes.